# Is Logobi a music genre?

Tags: genre, genre-characteristics

The English Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logobi):

> Logobi is an urban musical genre that accompanies certain dance moves.

On the opposite, The [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logobi) describes Logobi as a **dance** that can be accompanied by any fast and repetitive music, such as tracks of the Coupé-décalé genre.

So, is Logobi a music genre? If yes, what are its *musical* characteristics?

Comment: It's not impossible for it to be both.  "Salsa" is both a musical style and a dance.  They typically go together, but you can have one without the other.  The same is true for "swing."

Comment: @ChrisSunami: Indeed! If it is the case, an answer explaining this (with references if possible) would be very appreciated. The fact that salsa is (among others) a music genre can be proved by explaining [its musical characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa_music#Music_structure), so if Logobi is indeed also a music genre then the answer should describe its musical characteristics. Cheers!